# Computer will only connect to home network

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, internet-connection

My computer refuses to connect to any other network besides my home network. Other networks will be detected, and I seem to be able to log onto them, but then it shows that network has "no internet, secured." My school ITS can't seem to find the problem, even triple-checking that the MAC address registered in the school system is correct. (Is Windows 10 the problem? I upgraded half a year ago and could connect to other networks last week...)

Comment: Can you please provide the network configuration settings you're using?

Comment: ... Also the brand and model number of PC/Laptop.  The caveat on Windows 10 is that driver updates can happen any time if you're not careful.   And since you could connect a week or two ago, you might also look to see if you have any system restore points to go back to and see if they work.

Comment: Have you checked whether the WiFi adapter's IP address &c. are set statically, or via DHCP?

Comment: My computer is a Spectre 360 by HP model number 13-4005dx. I will try doing a system restore (I found a "critical windows update" that was done last week) and see if that works.

Comment: I rebooted my computer and set the BIOS settings back to default, and now it works! Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Please do not esit the title to include fixed as you might do on a forum. Thi sis not a forum. This is a Q&A site. If you found a real solution then please post it as an answer (and after a delay accept it). If you do not think that the question is relevant anymore you could also delete it. Esp since it has no answers and thus no guidance to other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my computer while resetting my BIOS settings (pressing F10 multiple times, F9, etc).